# Align article, bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hello i have problem when i have first article col-8 and next others just col-4 so then always articles align on new row on page and i need them align to top, under articles without space like this: [image: image:]

thanks for any help :-)

Comment: original web is here http://sasha.beepvix.com/

Comment: This is called a masonry layout it's not part of bootstrap. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've posted your issue twice. Please edit your question.

Second,

> i need quickly solve this problem

This sentence is useless.

To answer you, you want the behavior of a website like pinterest. Here is some stackoverflow topics that can help you:

- [Making a Pinterest-like grid with Bootstrap: the boxes are not displayed right below each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148063/making-a-pinterest-like-grid-with-bootstrap-the-boxes-are-not-displayed-right-b)
- [Is it possible to create a pinterest-like layout with Bootstrap only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570559/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pinterest-like-layout-with-bootstrap-only)

And this google search:

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=bootstrap+like+pinterest&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=AZxnVLm-M82HOqabgPgM

Comment: thank you for answer but with js i can write it too, i want something without js...

Comment: why? I think that there isn't simple CSS-only solution.